# Why Angular Material input looks like normal input?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to use An angular material input, but when i try to use it, it looks like a normal html input instead of an Angular Material input.
It looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXKly.png)
Instead of looking like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuNlb.png)

This is the html file of the component:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Supplier</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="training.supplier" name="supplier">
</mat-form-field>
```

This is the ts file of the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Training} from "../training";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-st-form',
  templateUrl: './st-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./st-form.component.css']
})
export class StFormComponent {

    training: Training;
}
```

I also use angular material in other components but it's working there.

Comment: Have you applied the Angular Material theme in your global CSS for your Angular app?

Comment: Did you import `MatInputModule` in the module which declares your component? Also check your browser console for runtime errors. You declare attribute `training` but never initialize it, and in the template you are using `training.supplier`. However `training` is `undefined` which could cause an error.

Comment: You were, there was an error in the console because training was undefined, after initializing it the error disapeared and now everything works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that training was declared but not initialized.
That line should look like this:

```
training: Training= new Training();
```

Also when having this problem, check the console for errors, I forgot to check it, and the error was in the console.